# what does "google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);" mean?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What does this mean?

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have the function 'initialize()' but I also added two paramters, longitude and latitude so it's like this:

```
function initialize(longitude, latitude){

}
```

because of this do I have to do anything to the 'initialize' in the line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [google.maps.event.addDomListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener) adds a DOM event listener, in this case to the `window` object, for the 'load' event, and specifies a function to run.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener):

> addDomListener(instance:Object, eventName:string, handler:function(?), capture?:boolean)
> **Return Value:** MapsEventListener
> Cross browser event handler registration. This listener is removed by calling removeListener(handle) for the handle that is returned by this function.

The `initialize` in `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` is a function pointer, you can't pass arguments with that.  To pass in arguments, wrap it in an anonymous function (that doesn't take arguments):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
   initialize(latitude, longitude);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it calls `initialize` when the DOM is loaded, but probably without the parameters, if I [interpret the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener) correctly.

But you could wrap the call inside another function and pass that to the method. It can be an anonymous function, like so:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){
  initialize(50.0000, 60.0000);
});
```